# Remove parts from url when rewriting

Tags: magento, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a Magento installation and want to rewrite the url and remove index.php and the trailing '/' from it

e.g. rewrite
http://www.domain.com/index.php/ to http://www.domain.com 
http://www.domain.com/index.php/customer/account/login/ to http://www.domain.com/customer/account/login

etc etc.
So not for these 2 urls but for all urls.

I currently have this in my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Magento SEO: remove index.php from URL">
    <match url="^(?!index.php)([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(media|skin|js)/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With the above web.config, the urls do not seem to be rewritten at all, but are just kept as-is.

Comment: You also need an outbound rule if you want to remove index.php from your links.

Comment: And how would I go about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my suggestion that thing could not help you.

but as i was faced problem you can follow below things to solve your issue.

**step 1:** Goto to your site root folder and you can find the htaccess file there.Open it on text editor and find the line `#Rewrite Base/` magento. Just replace it with `Rewrite Base/`

**step 2:** Then goto your admin panel and enable the Rewrites(set yes for Use Web Server Rewrites). You can find it at `System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization`.

**step 3:** Then goto Cache management page (system cache management ) and refresh your cache and refresh to check the site.

hope this will help you.

Comment: This rule removes the /magento part from my URL right? I don't have the /magento in my url since I placed the contents of the magento folder in my website root. It would not help to uncomment the line you refer to then right?

Comment: no it is not.it will just remove index.php from your magento setup for all action. pls try with above